# Motion of a bead along a frictionless rotating rod (constant angular velocity along one of it's ends, which is fixed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

There's a horizontally placed rod, fixed on a vertical axis at one end, so it doesn't fall on the ground with acceleration $g$, and stays horizontal, there is a bead (mass $m$) near that end point through which the rod passes, and the bead is free to move along the rod without friction. If the rod has constant angular velocity $\omega$ along the fixed end point, we observe that the bead starts moving outwards, with an acceleration increasing as the distance from fixed end point increases, why does this motion of bead happen? I mean the calculations are easy from the rotating frame of bead, as centrifugal force enters the scenario. But how will this outward motion be explained from ground FOR, what exactly is pulling it outwards? Please answer it using highschool level mechanics.